# generics type parameter hiding the type

Tags: java, generics

I created the interface Card as follows

```
  public interface Card extends Comparable<Card> {
    .....
    }

then 

    public interface Deck<Card> {
          public void add(Card card);
    }
```

In Deck interface with type parameter  I'm getting the warning ***type parameter is hiding the type Card***. I can as well declare the type T instead of Card but it makes more sense that the Deck to hold the Card Objects not more than that.

I read some old posts but not getting the clear sense of why the warning and what exactly the practical significance / why the compiler is complaining.

Comment: I usually use `TCard` naming in similar scenarios. I am afraid there are only opinion based answers to this question.

Comment: try public interface Deck<T extends Card> (however, this is not the correct way imho to do this, you dont need Deck to be a generic interface)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Deck<Card>
```

specifies the word "Card" as a placeholder for a type within the Deck class, the same way that

```
Deck<T>
```

does: it's just a placeholder.

If you never intend a deck to hold anything other than cards, your best option is to get rid of the generic type in Deck all together.

Answer (score 0):

Generics mean that you want a class which can work with different datatypes based on the specific type you want for a particular instance. For example consider these lists : the first list can hold integers and the second list can hold string and can provide all the operations irrespective of the datatype used in a particular instance.

`List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
 List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();`

In case you do not want the deck to store any thing other than `Card` then it does not justify the use for generics.

For the second part so to why compiler is showing a warning is because the `Deck` interface is just considering `<Card>` as a place holder and not the `Card` interface. Thus to explicitly tell you this the compiler is showing this warning.